# AutoForm- Access value of array of object's properties inside template

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I have defined an array of objects in my schema and now want to show objects properties into my template but not getting how to do it.

```
   ingredients: {
            type: [Object],
            minCount: 1
        },

    "ingredients.$.name": {
    type: String
        },
    "ingredients.$.amount": {
    type: String
    }
```

and trying to access them inside template

```
<li class="list-group-item">{{ingredients.$.name}} - {{ingredients.$.amount}}</li>
```

so can you please help me how to access them inside template.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that I understand correctly and that you have a collection with data in that schema, then you just need to get that data (e.g., with a helper called `ingredients`) and then use `#each` in your template:

```
{{#each ingredients}}
   <li class="list-group-item">{{name}} - {{amount}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: well ingredients is not collection by it self rather part of collection Recipes.When a user click on recipe on the page which is showing list of  all recipes then a specific page open just for the recipe being clicked with complete detail of it.And on that page i want to show list of its ingredients too.You can have look at my source code https://github.com/soni1/foody

Comment: I think with my answer and the documentation you should be figure the rest out. Just think about what the helper function needs to return. I'm not going to read your entire code.